# Did I miss a code or something?

Tags: c++

so I'm trying to write a guess the number game in C++.The computer is Supposed to take a random number with 4 digits then the player should enter a number too.Rules are:
if the computer chooses:1234
And the player enters:1356
1 must be displayed in green,3 must in yellow since it's in the wrong place and 5&6 in red.the game goes on till the player gets the right answer.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <windows.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <time.h>
#include<unistd.h> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int b;

HANDLE handle=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
cout<<"System is now generating a number...."<<"\n";

int *Number = new int[4];

 srand (time(NULL));
for(int counter=0;counter<4;)
{
Number[counter]=(rand()%9)+1;

if(Number[counter]!=Number[counter-1]&Number[counter]!=Number[counter-2]
  2]&Number[counter]!=Number[counter-3])         
{
 counter ++;
}
else
{
counter--;
}
}
cout<<Number[0]<<Number[1]<<Number[2]<<Number[3]<<"\n";

int *Guess=new int[4];
cout<<"please enter 4 digits for your number"<<"\n";
for(int counterG=0;counterG<4;counterG++) //line 34
{
cin>>Guess[counterG];
for(int counter;counter<4&counter>0;)
{

if((counter=counterG)&(Guess[counterG]=Number[counter])) //line 40
{
b=Guess[counterG];
SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle,10);
cout<<b<<"\n";

}
if((counter=counterG)&(Guess[counterG]==Number[counter- 1]|Guess[counterG]==Number[counter+1]|Guess[counterG]==Number[counter-2]|Guess[counterG]==Number[counter+2]))
{
b=Guess[counterG];
SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle,14);
cout<<b<<"\n";

}
else
{
b=Guess[counterG];
SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle,12);
cout<<b<<"\n";
}
}

}
```

now the program is fine until line 34 but nothing happens after that!
[It just gets the player digits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVvT8.png)
I'd be glad if you could tell me what I've done wrong

Comment: What did you observe, when stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Aside - getting formatting right will make you friends.  Getting it wrong will result in bugs weird and wonderful.

Comment: `if((counter=counterG)&(` - did you really intend (a) assignment instead of equivalence comparison, and (b) bitwise AND, in those statements? Likewise for your for-condition like `counter<4&counter>0` ?? And this code is *littered* with out-of-bounds access to your arrays. I think you need to hit the study materials again.

Comment: that's the problem whenever I try to use the debugger my system goes crazy...@ Algirdas Preidžius

Comment: @DeathStarAlloy I fail to understand how that is possible. I did recommend using debuggers, not random viruses.

Comment: A way to avoid this craziness is to work in smaller steps. Split up your functionality.  Implement a part, make sure that works and then continue.  The yellow score is the most difficult, so first present the board, then get input, then score green and finally score yellow.

Comment: Maybe it's time to reinstall your OS. I mean if your debugger causes the system to go crazy you likely have a virus.

Comment: I was trying to make the comparison when the number of the arrays are the same like Number[1] with Guess[1] so thought it would be best if I set counter =counterG-@ WhozCraig

Comment: Dude, your logic is wrong.....
Please correct it

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but it's too long for a comment:

```
if(Number[counter]!=Number[counter-1]&Number[counter]!=Number[counter-2]
  2]&Number[counter]!=Number[counter-3])
```

This line alone contains a lot of errors:

1. To have the logical AND operator you need `&&`, not `&`.
2. You have typed an extra `2]` at the beginning of the second line. I hope it's just a typo that you introduced when writing the question.
3. The first time you run this, `counter` is 0. What happens when you try to access `Number[counter-3]`? It's an out of bounds access, which leads to Undefined Behaviour, which can lead to anything.

And there are probably many more.

What to do now:

1. Work on your code indentation. It's really bad.
2. Start from a much simpler program, and verify that it works. Then, add one small step, verify it, and don't move on until you are happy with the result
3. Turn on your compiler warnings. Warnings are your friends, not a boring annoyance
4. Learn how to use a debugger. You won't go very far without debugging.

Answer (score -1):

1- replace & with &&(AND operator)

2- take input in a simple integer variable and then validate the number by performing  first check of number  greater than 0 and less than 9999.

3- then seperate digits from this variable and then assign those digits to aaray indexes respectvely.

Comment: I think this is comment material since its only some of several errors and OP's problem is quite deeper

Comment: i could not comment .. so i posted as answer